# How can I make Frama-c work with Coq-8.5?

Tags: coq, frama-c

I am trying to run the `swap.c` example from frama-c WP plug-in tutorial with coq, but I am getting the following compilation error for `BuiltIn.v` file;

```
$frama-c -wp -wp-rte -wp-proof coq swap.c

[kernel] Parsing FRAMAC_SHARE/libc/__fc_builtin_for_normalization.i (no preprocessing)
[kernel] Parsing swap.c (with preprocessing)
[rte] annotating function swap
[wp] 5 goals scheduled
[wp] [Coq] Compiling 'BuiltIn.v'.
[wp] [Coq] 'BuiltIn.v' compilation failed.
Don't know what to do with -as bool -as int -as real -as map
See -help for the list of supported options
[wp] [Coq] Compiling 'BuiltIn.v'.
[wp] [Coq] 'BuiltIn.v' compilation failed.
Don't know what to do with -as bool -as int -as real -as map
See -help for the list of supported options
[wp] [Coq] Compiling 'BuiltIn.v'.
[wp] [Coq] 'BuiltIn.v' compilation failed.
Don't know what to do with -as bool -as int -as real -as map
See -help for the list of supported options
[wp] [Coq] Goal typed_swap_post : Failed
     Error: Compilation of 'BuiltIn.v' failed.
[wp] [Coq] Goal typed_swap_assert_rte_mem_access_3 : Failed
     Error: Compilation of 'BuiltIn.v' failed.
[wp] [Coq] Goal typed_swap_assert_rte_mem_access : Failed
     Error: Compilation of 'BuiltIn.v' failed.
[wp] Proved goals:    2 / 5
     Qed:             2  (0.13ms-2ms)
     Coq:             0  (failed: 3)
```

Versions; Frama-c Magnesium-20151002, Coq 8.5, OCaml 4.02.3

According to frama-c website, 8.4+ should be okay, but I think it is not!
The problem is the version of Coq (I think).

WP plug-in tutorial list `-wp-coq-opt` option to pass coqc options. So I tried following;

```
frama-c -wp -wp-rte -wp-proof coqide -wp-coq-opt="-compat 8.4" swap.c
[kernel] user error: option `-wp-coq-opt=-compat 8.4' is unknown
```

Did not work! Any solutions to this?

Comment: Downgraded to Coq 8.4.6. No compilation errors!

Comment: Support for Coq 8.5 will be available in the next version of Frama-C. For now, downgrading is indeed your best option.

Comment: Thanks for the information.